# Modifying multidimensional numpy subarrays indexed by lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, scipy

Lets say I have a 4x4 numpy array: `quad = arange(16).reshape(4,4)`, i.e.

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]]
```

and I want to change the elements with values,

```
[[ 5  7]
 [ 9 11]]
```

to (for example),

```
[[16 17]
 [18 19]]
```

My initial guess was that I could do something like,

```
quad[[1,3],[1,3]] = np.arange(16,20).reshape(2,2)
```

but that doesn't work, as `quad[[1,3],[1,3]]` actually yields the elements corresponding to [5,11].  I found that I could **view** the appropriate elements using `quad[[1,3]][:,[1,3]]` but I can't use that to modify those values.

Is the only solution to use a `for` loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
quad[np.ix_([1, 3], [1, 3])]
```

This is shorthand for:

```
x = [[1, 1], [3, 3]]
y = [[1, 3], [1, 3]]
quad[x, y]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a behaviour of [integer indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer) in Numpy. If you give as index of an N-dimentional array `A` a tuple `(m_1...m_n)` of N 1d arrays of size M, then the slice is constructed as

```
result[m_1, ..., m_n] == np.array([A[m_1[0], ..., m_n[0]], A[m_1[1], ..., m_n[1]],
                           ..., A[m_1[M], ..., m_n[M]]]
```

To overcome this behaviour, you can use slice indexing twice:

```
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
>>> a[1:3][:,1:3]
array([[ 5,  6],
       [ 9, 10]])
```

UPD: You can modify this view:

```
>>> b = np.arange(16,20).reshape(2,2)
>>> b
array([[16, 17],
       [18, 19]])
>>> a[1:3][:,1:3] = b
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4, 16, 17,  7],
       [ 8, 18, 19, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I modified my question somewhat while you were answering, my apologies -- I actually need to *modify* the given values, which this technique doesn't seem to allow